# Lombok not generating boilerplate in .class file and can't find any solutions

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module, lombok

I'm trying to create a modular javafx application using maven and hibernate. Yesterday, I was getting a lot of errors in my module-info.java file and so I decided to re-create the project from scratch to isolate the problem.

The project won't compile as the IDE can't find the lombok-generated methods. When I checked the .class file, it didn't have any the of auto-generated boilerplate. I don't get this problem when I don't have a module-info.java file.

Following some suggestions I saw in other posts regarding lombok, I've made sure that the annotation processing is enabled and a lombok plug-in is enabled in IntelliJ. 
When I add the lombok.jar to my dependencies in project structure, the module-info.jar doesn't compile, and intelliJ displays "Ambiguous module reference: lombok" when I place cursor over 'requires lombok'. 
The module declaration is also underlined in red, displaying the following message: "Module 'AlienDB' reads package 'lombok' from both 'lombok' and 'lombok'.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Aliens</groupId>
  <artifactId>AlienDB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>AlienDB</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

module-info.java file:

```
module AlienDB {

    requires lombok;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.naming;

    exports Aliens;
}
```

Alien1.java

```
package Aliens;

import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity (name = "alien2")
public class Alien1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "aID", nullable = false)
    private int aID;

    @Column(name = "aName")
    private String aName;


}
```

main app:

```
package Aliens;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )

    {
        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Alien1.class);
        ServiceRegistry reg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(con.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory(reg);

        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Alien1 alienName = session.get(Alien1.class, 1);
        //System.out.println(alienName.getAName());

        tx.commit();

        session.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the app as it is shown above, with lombok jar added to the dependencies, I get the following error:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module lombok does not read a module that exports org.mapstruct.ap.spi

When I remove lombok.jar from the dependencies in project structure, module-info.jar does not show any errors but I get the following error:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module lombok not found, required by AlienDB

In either case, when I un-comment the print line statement, I get the following method, presumably because lombok hasn't been able to generate the boilerplate:

Error:(24, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAName()
  location: variable alienName of type Aliens.Alien1

module structure:

```
C:.
├───.idea
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───Aliens
│   │   └───resources
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───Aliens
└───target
    ├───classes
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    ├───generated-test-sources
    │   └───test-annotations
    ├───maven-archiver
    ├───maven-status
    │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├───compile
    │       │   └───default-compile
    │       └───testCompile
    │           └───default-testCompile
    ├───surefire-reports
    └───test-classes
        ├───Aliens
        └───META-INF
```

I'm using intelliJ ultimate 2019.1 
SDK is java 11 
Language level is set to 9.

EDIT: I've tried to run it on Eclipse as well and I get the same issue - Lombok methods aren't being generated, even though they appear as a valid suggestion in the suggestion box.

Comment: Did you enable annotation processing?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the latest version of the IDE plugin?

Comment: Yes, the annotation processing was enabled and the plug-in didn't have an update for it in intelliJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the following my pom.xml file.

```
 <configuration>
            <source>9</source>
            <target>9</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.8</version>
              </annotationProcessorPath>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

This was one the closest issues I have been having in IntelliJ - my error is:

> ```
> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module lombok not found, required by com.example.demo
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

But the solution that was posted here did not help. I will probably create a new question with all the steps from scratch. But if by that point someone can give an extra idea here I would be quite happy.

EDIT:

I was able to solve in on my end with using the keyword `static`

> requires static lombok;

Comment: Ok. I think I got it on my end. I was missing "static" keyword. 

**requires static lombok;**

Hopefully this might help anyone.